# how to set Label into NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel

Hi I got 2 labels textview and labelsText and in this method they are string1 and string2 but I can't really get it work to make textview string1 and labelsText string2

this is the code:

```
-(void)findEqualsIn:(NSString *)string1 and:(NSString *)string2 {
    NSMutableArray *string1chars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *string2chars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    //filling the string1chars array
    for (int i = 0; i < [string1 length]; i++) {
        [string1chars addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [string1 characterAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    //filling the string2chars array
    for (int i = 0; i < [string2 length]; i++) {
        [string2chars addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [string2 characterAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    //checking if they have some letters in common on the same spot
    for (int i = 0; i < [string1chars count] && i < [string2chars count]; i++) {
        if ([[string1chars objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[string2chars objectAtIndex:i]]) {
            //change the color of the character at index i to green
        } else {
            //change the color of the character at index i to the standard color

        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it HAVE to be 1 label or is it allright if there are a couple of labels sticked next to eachother (user cant see differance).

Comment: next time, please indent your code.

Comment: dragon cAn you get back on me at the other question can You help me there because I can't get this final thing together, after it my app is done :P & je bent nl toch?

Comment: I wanted it to be different Labels that would make it easier becauseI would be able to to compare all the labels. The thing is that It's a random word generator with word length of 6, I can't get do that in labels with length 1 right? Ideal would be to have 1 label with the random word 1 label with the input and be able to separate those 2 label in 6 different, 12 in total and then I can compare those. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple labels with each one letter in it and make it appear like they are in only 1 label. This would require something like this:

```
//make sure the first word is always the one the user gave so you don't show him/her the hidden string
- (void)outputColoredLabelsTo:(UIView *)theView with:(NSString *)word1 and:(NSString *)word2 {
    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 0, 0)] autorelease];

    for (int i = 0; i < [word1 length] && i < [word2 length]; i++) {
        NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [word1 characterAtIndex:i]];
        CGSize size = [value sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]];
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x + label.frame.size.width, label.frame.origin.y, size.width, size.height)];
        [label setText:value];

        if ([word1 characterAtIndex:i] == [word2 characterAtIndex:i]) {
            NSLog(@"Match found at index %i (letter %c)", i, [word1 characterAtIndex:i]);
            [label setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"No match found at index %i (printing letter %c)", i, [word1 characterAtIndex:1]);
            [label setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        }

        [theView addSubview:label];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All text in a `uilabel` or `uitextview` has to be the same font/color.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no built-in component for richt text in iOS SDK few implementations are still available. I recommend you to use [FTCoreText](https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTCoreText) for creating UILabels (not editable) and for editable [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView).